# How to change location of tooltip box?

Tags: r, svg, tooltip

In RSVGTipsDevice, default positioning of tooltip box occludes other regions of the image (or plot). Is there a way to place tooltip box at the bottom/top of the plot, so that it doesn't block other data-points ?

Screenshot of defalut tooltip layout :

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3tgXHsXj9tBeEFXLUg3X3J3eW8

(short) code used for producing above plot :

```
sapply(k, function(k) {
  setSVGShapeToolTip(desc1 = k, desc2 = centroid_list[k, 1])
  points(scores[k,1], scores[k,2], pch = pch_list[i], 
         cex = 2, col = color_set[y])
 })
```